# ButterKnife Bind in Fragment using different layouts

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, butterknife

I am trying to develop an Android application using fragments and I stumbled on a problem while trying to use Butterknife to binds views and use @OnClick annotation.

In my fragment I inflate different layouts depending on user's selection in menu. Lets say user selects settings so I then inflate my settings layout which holds button for logout. If user selects sync in menu I inflate my sync view which holds button to start sync.

My onCreateView looks something like the following code:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
View rootView = null;
if(settings)
{
    rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.settings_view, container, false);
} else {
    rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.sync_view, container, false);
}
return rootView;
```

}

So then I created my @Onclick method for logout button

```
@OnClick(R.id.btnSettingsLogout)
    public void logout() {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Button was pressed!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

and added `ButterKnife.bind(this, rootView);` to the end of my onCreateView method befure I return rootView.

The problem is that now when I inflate my settings view everything works and I am greeted with toast message whenever I press my logout button but when I inflate my sync view application crashes because of the following exception:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to bind views for si.vitez.testapp.DetailFragment
```

Is it possible to inject both views, so application won't crash no mater which of the two views will be inflated?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should use `@Nullable` annotation for you method.

```
@Nullabale
@OnClick(R.id.yourId)
public void onClickMethod(){
 // your code
}
```

see [here](http://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife/) for more information about this.